# Azure DevOps direct access to Agent Environment Variables

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a way to get a direct access to environment variables defined on my agent? I want to use environment variables from my agent inside a pipeline task.

My current workaround looks like:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SQL_SERVER]$($env:SQL_SERVER)"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SQL_MODEL]$($env:SQL_MODEL)"
```

Which I added in a **PowerShell Inline Task** before the Variable `$(SQL_SERVER)` get used in my Pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#environment-variables

> Environment variables are specific to the operating system you are
> using. They are injected into a pipeline in platform-specific ways.
> The format corresponds to how environment variables get formatted for
> your specific scripting platform.
>
> On UNIX systems (macOS and Linux), environment variables have the
> format `$NAME`. On Windows, the format is `%NAME%` for batch and
> `$env:NAME` in PowerShell.
>
> System and user-defined variables also get injected as environment
> variables for your platform. When variables are turned into
> environment variables, variable names become uppercase, and periods
> turn into underscores. For example, the variable name `any.variable`
> becomes the variable name `$ANY_VARIABLE`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I try `$(sql.server)`, `$(%SQL_SERVER%)`, `$($SQL_SERVER)`, `%SQL_SERVER%`, `$SQL_SERVER`, `$env:SQL_SERVER` in my pipeline. Non of them get substituted by the value of my environment variable. Could you also give an interpretation to your answer?

Comment: How did you define the variable? How did you want to use this variable? And which platform did you use?

Comment: Windows, I add the variable to System Variables over `System > Environment Variables > New`. So local it is accessible with `$env:SQL_SERVER`. I want to use this variable to pass it directly into a pipeline task, without work around like I post in my question.

Comment: Please go to your agent pool and check the Capabilities of the agent you are using, to check whether you can see `sql.server` capability. If you can not see this capability, try to restart your agent service, then you should be able to print the variable using `Write-Host "$(sql.server)"`.

Comment: Right, this is the behavior I would expect for a normal self hosted agent. But forgot something. In this case it is a `Deployment Group` agent. It has defined the environment variables (work with the workaround), but in `Capabilities` there is nothing defined. Are `Deployment Group` Agents limited?

Comment: OK, I am sorry. I test it an the environment variable name is also direct accessible inside the pipeline, also on a `Deployment Group` agent. **Environment Variable** = `SQL_SERVER` -> **Pipeline** = `$(SQL_SERVER)`

Comment: Do you mean you managed to reference a *agent environment variable* directly from a YAML task ? I am trying to do the same thing without success. I seems the only way is to use a Bash/Powershell task to create & set a pipeline variable from the shell-specific syntax ($ / %% / $env:). I would prefer to use it directly using $(XXX) in my YAML, which would be cross-platform, is it possible ?